# How to add series to a Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

How to add the 'result' series to the 'my_data' Dataframe?
Both are having same size  of 355 rows.
[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIlRJ.jpg)

Comment: It seems you not read comment under previous question, because same question. why?

Comment: I dont know to to append it to dataframe.\